# Google forms set automatically answer based on selection

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Forms where one of the fields is a dropdown to select a department. When choosing the department, I want a column for email to appear in my responses, but I want it to be already filled in without having to select it. For example, when selecting 'Human Resources', I want the email answer to be set to hr@test.com. What is the best way to do this, use Apps Script or link to another spreadsheet containing all the emails?

Comment: I am not familiar with the whole flow of how you pull and answer your forms but will this help? [Google Forms - validate answer criteria based on previous responses (read from spreadsheet?)](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/58400433/google-forms-validate-answer-criteria-based-on-previous-responses-read-from-spreadsheet?hl=en).Moreover, If I understood your concern correctly, there is `three dot` on the top-right corner toolbar which is a feature on google form which allows you to store your default answers in a `pre-filled link`. On the other hand, I would suggest for you to use `webapp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, it is best practice to leave the Form Responses sheet as is.  (Although you can hide it if you want.)  Then on another sheet, do whatever calculations you wish.  The way I would set it up is to have a Form Responses sheet, a Department Emails sheet, and a Form Responses with Modifications sheet.

The Department Email sheet would have department list in column A and the corresponding emails in column B.

If department names are entered in column B of your Form Responses sheet, I would use `=ARRAYFORMULA('Form Responses'!B2:B)` in B2 of Form Responses with Modification Sheet. In C2 I would use something like this to find the emails corresponding to the department name in the respective form response:

```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B="",,XLOOKUP(B2:B,'Department Emails'!A2:A,'Department Emails'!B2:B))),"No assigned email")
```

All other needed columns from Form Responses can be displayed using `=ARRAYFORMULA('Form Responses'!x2:x)` with *x* being the required column letter.

Hopefully, that all made sense. :)

Answer (score 0):

I also would leave the linked sheet alone simply to serve as a backup for submitted data.

> You will have to create an installable onFormSubmit trigger and name it appropriately in this case onFormSubmit.  There are no simple triggers for form submission.

```
/**
 * Assume column one is a datavalidation of require in list ["A","B","C"] and A,B,C are properties of an object like const eobj = {"A":email1,"B":email2, "C":email3}
 * Also assume that you are not using the linked sheet but instead you are leaving it alone and using the onFormSubmit to populate another sheet
 * then email recipient = eobj[e.values[1]] 
 */


   
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const sh = e.source.getSheetByName("Your sheet name");
  const eobj = {"A":email1,"B":email2, "C":email3};//edit as required
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1,1).setValue(eobj[e.value[1]]); //contains value of eobj[e.values[1]] which is used for email recipient for this row
}
```

You cannot run these functions without supplying the event object. If you attempt to run from the script editor without supplying the event object you will get an error.  The onEdit trigger is a simple trigger meaning that it cannot perform functions that require permission.  If you need to perform commands that require permission you must create an installable trigger either programmatically or through the editors trigger panel.

There are several limitations running scripts this way.  You will have difficulty using alert and prompt boxes.  They are fairly difficult to debug because the onEdit is not easily run in debug mode so you are left having to edit the appropriate elements on the desired sheet."

- [onEdit.restrictions()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)